# Getting data from NSURLConnection using blocking or similar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi guys this will be my first post and am pretty new to Objective-C though not entirely new to coding. I've been doing a lot of reading and a lot of Googling and a lot of my answers have come from this site. So now I'm really stuck I figured it was about time I asked the experts.

I'm basically trying to get the raw HTML data from a given URL so that I can parse it for information. I have all the parsing sorted, and can retrieve the raw HTML however I'm struggling to understand how to get the program to stop while the data arrives from `NSURLConnection` so I can use it. Currently my program whizzes past the connection and the holding String gets left as empty, until shortly after when its filled by the request. I believe I need to use a "Syncronous" connection but this is frowned upon because it freezes the UI while its processing the request. I'm trying to call it like this ....

```
urlData = [getURLClass getURL: @"http://www.google.co.uk"];
```

Hoping to get raw HTML in to the String `urlData` so I can parse it.My current code from my class is below....

```
//Create the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

//Open NSURLConnection with 'request'
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    //If we receive something
    if (data) {
        //Pass and decode to string
        receivedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Received HTML: %@", receivedData); 
    }

    //Something went wrong
    else {
       // ToDO: Sort out any errors

    }
}];

return receivedData;
```

When this is run the log shows "Received HTML: nil" and the return value is also blank, but if I wait a moment then call the class again its been filled with data from the previous request. I did try another method which the data was retrieved in to

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading
```

But this leaves me the problem that I cannot "return" the data from the Method that was called. As I said I'm very new to Objective-C. I'm aware there are discontinued wrappers like `ASIHTTPRequest`, but I'm sure there is a simpler answer to this than using someone else's class. It will also help me to learn if I can find an answer, I simply need to get the program to wait while the data is received before the class return it. I may be trying to run before I can walk with Obj-C, but my program is useless unless I can interact with the web.

Thanks in advance.
Plasma

Comment: Try logging the error object as well to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I know exactly whats going wrong, the data gets filled after the variable is returned. I want to know how to stop this happening.

Comment: Ok so I have found a solution basically I remove the above [NSURLconnection sendAsynchronousRequest and replace with ...    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a class file for this type of situation.

CAURLDownload.h:
http://localhostr.com/file/vGtIIpO/CAURLDownload.h

CAURLDownload.m:
http://localhostr.com/file/TAieiAE/CAURLDownload.m

Basically, you want to call
`[CAURLDownload downloadURL:URL target:self selector:@selector(finishedSelector: connection:) failSelector:@selector(failureSelector:) userInfo:userInfo];`

URL is an NSURL and userInfo is an NSDictionary.

Basically, you call that method with the appropriate parameters and execute your parsing in finishedSelector. Example:

```
[CAURLDownload downloadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://couleeapps.hostei.com"]
                    target:self
                  selector:@selector(downloadFinished:connection:)
              failSelector:@selector(downloadFailed:)
                  userInfo:nil];
```

And for the methods:

```
- (void)downloadFinished:(NSData *)recievedData conneciton:(CAURLDownload *)connection {
    //Parse recievedData
    NSString *recievedString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:recievedData] autorelease];
    //Etc.
}

- (void)downloadFailed:(CAURLDownload *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Download Failed!");
    //Do something
}
```

This has both the upsides of not locking the UI, being memory-friendly, and callable without a pointer required (singleton).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the links, I can already do this with some experiments I've tried already. My problem is I want to reuse this over and over and each time parse for different bits of info from different urls, coding all these different parsing routines in to the "downloadFinished" gives me the same problem as I have with "connectionDidFinishLoading". I want to be able to call a URL into a String variable preferably with one line of code. I can then immediatley parse that variable for the info I need. then call another URL.

Comment: I guess I'm not expressly bothered about not locking the UI as I won't be accepting any input while the URL is loading anyway if that makes any difference. I can see this example being good for downloading something in the background while the use continues to do other stuff with the app.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you want with the **NSString** function **initWithContentsOfURL**:

```
NSError* error;
NSString* htmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

It might also be **NSASCIIStringEncoding** for the encoding ... but in any case it gives you the string synchronously.

EDIT:

Corrected Spelling initWithContent**s**OfURL, added alloc

Comment: Thanks for this, when I tried doing this I got an error in Xcode saying ... No known class method for selector "initWithContentOfURL:encoding:error:" .. BUT I may since have found an answer to my problem. As is usually the case when I puplicly ask for help then solve something I've been working on for days!!

Comment: Oops ... it is initWithContentsOfURL, with an 's' behind the content - sorry for the spelling mistake ...

Comment: I tried again and still get the same error just with 'initWithContentsOfURL' instead. :(

Comment: Ahem .. ok, ok, it's not a static function, but an instance function, so it has to be [NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL ... but you can also have a look at the NSString doc, it's explained there: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the SDK as supplied by Apple doesn't have any convenience functions to make this super simple.  You have to do it all yourself using NSURLConnection.  What I do is make a wrapper class that executes the NSURLConnection and then when the data is completely received it calls a completion block that you provide.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm trying to do, if its not too much trouble could you explain or show me how I might implement a completion block?

Comment: I've seen a few comments regarding this problem but never actually seen a reply that I understand. There was mention of Run Loops or something! :s Obviously showing my inexperience and noobie status here!! I'm happy to post a zip of my code somewhere if it helps people, but I think you all probably understand what I'm trying to achieve anyway.